# RegEx: Only start if nothing or space is before string

Tags: php, regex

Im bad at regex and I got stuck at this, I found a few links and sadly it didn't work.

```
$str = preg_replace("/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", '<span class="label label-default">$1</span>', $str);
$str = preg_replace("~/r(.*?)(?:<br>|$)~uis", '<font color="red">$1</font><br>', $str);
```

so currently both of these match the correct thing, they both do what I want.
For clarification: the first line does the next word to @ in a special css class, and the second line makes the textline after /r red. 
BUT the @ works also in things like asdsa@email.com and /r works in things like .com/r/test, both is not what I want.
I already tried this, but its not working :/

```
"/(^|[ ])@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/"
"/\b@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/"
```

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookbehind based regex:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=^| )@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/m', '<span class="label label-default">$1</span>', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~(?<=^| )/r(.*?)(?:<br>|$)~uims', '<font color="red">$1</font><br>', $str);
```

Here `(?<=^| )` is a lookbehid which means match your regex if it is preceded by space or is at line start.

Comment: strangely this doesn't work with the @ thing, if a space is before that it works but not at a line start. it does tho with the /r

Comment: What is your input string that is not matching?

Comment: nvm it works, but not with a string I tried it. I reposted it and it works. Dunno, anyway it works now, thank you

Comment: I've literally pasted 2 times the same text and one on it works, on one it works partly and on one it doesn't work at all

Comment: See I cannot guess these cases unless you provide me your input text.

Comment: this is my input text:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58347/discussion-between-user3112337-and-anubhava).